How can I compute a new value using HasDefaultValue() each time a record is inserted in Entity Framework Core?
Consider the following code:
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationNotification>().Property(p => p.NotifiedAt).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow);

The DateTime.UtcNow expression is only evaluated once, and each inserted has the same value for NotifiedAt. How can I compute unique values using HasDefaultValue()?
Note: I know about HasDefaultValueSql(), which instructs the database server to compute the value. But I don't want to rely on expressions, like GETDATE(), that may only be valid for a specific database server

I don't want to rely on function expressions, like GETDATE(), that may only be valid for a specific database server on the contrary, do depend on actual database constraints instead of client libraries ORMs. The primary actor is the database, not the ORM. The ORM is a leaky abstraction, used to Map Objects to Relational storage, not design the database. The database can ensure consistency no matter what client is used

HasDefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow) creates a database constraint with a hard-coded DateTime value set at the time the field is created. That doesn't make sense anyway. HasDefaultValue can't be used for generating values at runtime. So the strict answer to your question is: you can't. If you want to know how to use HasDefaultValueSql in one model targeting different database providers, then please rephrase your question accordingly.

Alternatively, you can implement ValueGenerator<DateTimeOffset> abstract class from Entity Framework.
Example implementation:
public class DateTimeOffsetGenerator : ValueGenerator<DateTimeOffset>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override DateTimeOffset Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        return DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }
}

And then you can use it like you would like in Fluent API:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.Created)
        .HasValueGenerator((_, _) => new DateTimeOffsetGenerator());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

Reference:

Generated Values
ValueGenerator Class


You can always override SaveChanges and respective methods and set needed column value. For example, if I want to set Created date for my entities upon creation, you can write following code:
private void UpdateMyEntities()
{
    var myEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>()
        .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
        .ToArray();

    Array.ForEach(myEntities, x => x.Entity.Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    UpdateMyEntities();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    UpdateMyEntities();
    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    UpdateMyEntities();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    UpdateMyEntities();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

